# How to merge REST style show pages by removing the resource id in google analytics

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, google-analytics, analytics

I have a rails application with REST routes like */documents/123/show*

Does anyone know how to filter this resource id (e.g. 123) out in a google analytics profile?

**Problem**

In my google analytics url lists a see the following paths separated:

- /documents/123/show
- /documents/3820/show
- /posts/387/edit
- /documents/378/edit

**Goal**

My goal is to merge those urls with the roles they have in the app.

- /documents/show
- /posts/edit
- /documents/edit

Does anyone know a filter to do that merge? Or is there a better solution that i'm missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is actually an example for a custom advanced filter in the GA admin interface (when you set up a new advanced filter in the admin section click on "filter help: advanced") that describes how to reorder url parts - it should be not too hard to adapt that to your needs.

Comment: Hello @gugl, please could you provide an answer if you get over it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how to merge, BUT you can send the PAGE that you want to GA.

You have to set the `page` value on the `tracker` **on each** page **before** you call `ga('send', 'pageview');`

in views/documents/show.html.erb:

```
ga('set', 'page', 'documents/show');
```

in views/posts/edit.html.erb

```
ga('set', 'page', 'posts/edit');
```

Of course you can go fancy and include this in your controller and in your layout

in layout/application.html.erb

```
  <script type="application/javascript">
     ... ga setup here

     <% if @ga_page.present? %>
        ga('set', 'page', '<%= @ga_page%>');
     <% end %>
     ga('send', 'pageview');
  </script>
```

Reference:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/pages#modifying_page_urls